# Finding all properties for a schema-less vertex class

Tags: python-3.x, orientdb, orientdb-2.1, pyorient

I have a class Node extends V. I add instances to Node with some set of document type information provided. I want to query the OrientDB database and return some information from Node; to display this in a formatted way I want a list of all possible field names (in my application, there are currently 115 field names, only one of which is a property used as an index)

To do this in pyorient, the only solution I found so far is (client is the name of the database handle):

```
count = client.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Node")[0].COUNT
node_records = client.query("SELECT FROM Node LIMIT {0}".format(count))
node_key_list = set([])
for node in node_records:
   node_key_list |= node.oRecordData.keys()
```

I figured that much out pretty much through trial and error. It isn't very efficient or elegant. Surely there must be a way to have the database return a list of all possible fields for a class or any other document-type object. Is there a simple way to do this through either pyorient or the SQL commands?

Comment: Hi @kingledion, do you want to retrieve a list of the names of all of the fields of a class ? Or also their values ?

Comment: Just the list of names, as you have done below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your case with this dataset:

[image]

And this is the structure of my class **`TestClass`**:

[image]

As you can see from my structure only **`name`**, **`surname`** and **`timeStamp`** have been created in **`schema-full`** mode, instead **`nameSchemaLess1`** and **`nameSchemaLess1`** have been inserted into the DB in **`schema-less`** mode.

After having done that, you could create a **Javascript function** in OrientDB Studio or Console (as explained [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Functions.html)) and subsequently you can recall it from **`pyOrient`** by using a **`SQL`** command.

The following posted function retrieves all the fields names of the class **`TestClass`** without duplicates:

**Javascript function:**

```
var g = orient.getGraph();

var fieldsList = [];
var query = g.command("sql", "SELECT FROM TestClass");
for (var x = 0; x < query.length; x++){
  var fields = query[x].getRecord().fieldNames();
  for (var y = 0; y < fields.length; y++) {
    if (fieldsList == false){
      fieldsList.push(fields[y]);
    } else {
      var fieldFound = false;
      for (var z = 0; z < fieldsList.length; z++){
        if (fields[y] == fieldsList[z]){
          fieldFound = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (fieldFound != true){
        fieldsList.push(fields[y]);
      }
    }
  }
}
return fieldsList;
```

**pyOrient code:**

```
import pyorient


db_name = 'TestDatabaseName'

print("Connecting to the server...")
client = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2424)
session_id = client.connect("root", "root")
print("OK - sessionID: ", session_id, "\n")

if client.db_exists(db_name, pyorient.STORAGE_TYPE_PLOCAL):
    client.db_open(db_name, "root", "root")
    functionCall = client.command("SELECT myFunction() UNWIND myFunction")
    for idx, val in enumerate(functionCall):
        print("Field name:  " + val.myFunction)

client.db_close()
```

**Output:**

```
Connecting to the server...
OK - sessionID:  54 

Field name:  name
Field name:  surname
Field name:  timeStamp
Field name:  out_testClassEdge
Field name:  nameSchemaLess1
Field name:  in_testClassEdge
Field name:  nameSchemaLess2
```

As you can see all of the fields names, both schema-full and schema-less, have been retrieved.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer Luca. I used it as shown below. I do want to ask you about why you used UNWIND? If you don't use unwind you get the data in pyorient as a dictionary entry which you can pull out in one chunk. Isn't that more desirable than creating a extra list to iterate through?

Comment: Hi @kingledion, thanks for voting. I used `UNWIND` only to retrieve all of the different fields as a non-list output (I thought about the case if someone would like to execute the query in **ODB Studio**, **Console**, ecc... as a single instruction) but you can change it in the way that you believe better. Glad to have been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Luca's answer worked. I modified it to fit my tastes/needs. Posting here to increase the amount of OrientDB documentation on Stack Exchange. I took Luca's answer and translated it to groovy. I also added a parameter to select the class to get fields for and removed the UNWIND in the results. Thank you to Luca for helping me learn.

Groovy code for function getFieldList with 1 parameter (class_name):

```
g = orient.getGraph()
fieldList = [] as Set
ret = g.command("sql", "SELECT FROM " + class_name)

for (record in ret) {
   fieldList.addAll(record.getRecord().fieldNames())
}
return fieldList
```

For the pyorient part, removing the database connection it looks like this:

```
node_keys = {}
ret = client.command("SELECT getFieldList({0})".format("'Node'"))
node_keys = ret[0].oRecordData['getFieldList']
```

Special notice to the class name; in the string passed to client.command(), the parameter must be encased in quotes.